# $f(0)=0, f(1/3)=3/5, f(1/2)=4/5,f(2/3)=12/13,f(1)=1$ What is $f$?

Tags: calculus

Can one find a simple, smooth closed form for a function $f$ that would be defined for $ 0 \leq x \leq 1 $ and would satisfy the 5 constraints mentionned in the title?

Context: let's call a "hopscotch" a geometrical construct made of 3 families of lines, the $D_m$, the $D'_n$, the $\Delta_k$, and satisfying: for any $m$ and any $n$, the intersection of $D_m$ and $D'_n$ lies on $\Delta_{mn}$. Let's call a straight hopscotch a hopscotch such that $D_1$ is the $x$-axis and for all $n$, $D'_n$ is the symmetric of $D_n$ relatively to $y = x$. Hopscotches and straight hopscotches do exist: for instance, the following two straight hopscotches exist:

- the logarithmic hopscotch, where

  - $D_m$ is $y = \log{m}$,
  - $D'_n$ is $x = \log{n}$,
  - $\Delta_k$ is $x+y = \log{k}$;
- the quadratic hopscotch, where

  - $D_m$ is $\left(1-m\right)x+\left(1+m\right)y=2\left(m^{2}-1\right)$,
  - $D'_n$ is $\left(1+n\right)x+\left(1-n\right)y=2\left(n^{2}-1\right)$,
  - $\Delta_k$ is $x+y=2k$.

[image: (the quadratic hopscotch)]

Let's try to find other straight hopscotches and assume that the equations for the $D_m$ and the $D'_n$ are:

- $D_m$: $a(m) y = x - b(m)$,
- $D'_n$: $a(n) x = y - b(n)$.

These notations are chosen such that:

- the $(a(m), 1)$ vector provides the direction of $D_m$,
- the $(b(n), 0)$ point is the intersection of $D_1$ and $D'_n$.

Without loss of generality one can assume that $b(2)=1$, since zooming in or zooming out a straight hopscotch still provides a straight hopscotch.

Our first degree of liberty is to chose $a(2)$. Let's say that $a(2) = t$, where $0 \leq t \leq 1$. Notice that the logaritmic hopscotch enters the category $t = 0$, while the quadratic the $t = \frac{1}{3}$.

Once $t$ is chosen, $b(4)$ can be computed: $2\times 2 = 4$ translates to $D_2 \cap D'_2$ lies on $\Delta_{4}$; since the hopscotch is straight, $\Delta_{4}$ has slope -1. And then, $\Delta_{4} \cap D_{1} = (b(4), 0)$. Once $b(4)$ is computed, we cannot make further progress. One has to make a new assumption. My choice of a second degree of liberty is on $a(4)$. Let's say that $a(4) = u$, where $0 \leq u \leq 1$.

Now, thanks to $2 \times 4 = 8$ we can compute $b(8)$; and thanks to $ 4 \times 4 = 16$ we can compute $b(16)$.

At this step, we're in situation where we know $b(1), b(2), b(4), b(8), b(16), a(1), a(2), a(4)$, but we still don't know the value of $a(8)$. There is a way to compute it, though, thanks to $2 \times 8 = 16$ used "backwards": $D'_8$ passes through $\Delta_{16} \cap D_{2}$. This process can be pursued to determine all
the $b(2^k)$ and all the $a(2^k)$. Let's limit us to the $2^k$ and partially draw the hopscotch (under the graphical tool Desmos, for instance) with all these lines.

When we play with the values of $t$ and $u$ and see how the lines behave, something is striking. Some hopscotches have their $b(2^k)$ monotonically increasing, some others do not. Some hopscotches have their $a(2^k) \geq 0$, some others do not. So what happens if we focus on the hopscotches that have the extra constraints $b(2^k)$ monotonically increasing and their $a(2^k) \geq 0$ ?
Well, it appears that this forces $u$ to be unique and function of $t$.
I was able to determine the value of $u = f(t)$ by tedious semi-programmatic/semi-manual methods for a few rational $t$'s and was confident enough that the results always were rational. But I could not guess what $f$ was.

Here is how identifying $f$ was submitted here.

[image: the quadratic hopscotch, annotated with f]

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial

Comment: Did you try Lagrange polynomials?

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I didn't know about Lagrange polynomials.

Comment: Yes, I can. $ $

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course $f$ is not uniquely defined by a finite collection of points, but if we note that the denominators are sums of squares we might render

$(0^2+1^2)f(0/1)=0=2×0×1$

$(1^2+3^2)f(1/3)=6=2×1×3$

$(1^2+2^2)f(1/2)=4=2×1×2$

...

And identify $f(x)=2x/(1+x^2)$.

Comment: Excellent. This is what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Lagrange polynomials give
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{65}x(54x^3 - 99x^2 - 24x + 134)$$